# How to subset data with multiple criteria from one column

Tags: r, subset

I need to create a data subset from multiple "inclusion" criteria from a column (V5:Format) of my df.

I have tried :

```
new.data <- old.data[grep("text1", old.data$V5), ]
```

This works for 1 inclusion criteria. I want to add a second inclusion criteria - data must include "text1" & "text2" for data subset

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make it easier to read/understand [edit] your question to properly format input, output, and code using the editors `{}` button or indent 4 spaces manually. The UNIX tool `grep` mentioned in your tag doesn't have a function named `subset()` or any other functions so if this is really about some function that just happens to also be named `grep` in some other tool then please add the tag for whatever tool that is and remove the tag for UNIX's `grep`.

Comment: Thanks Ed -  very new to this area of science (+community) and appreciate guidance on making my requests more concise. I have (heavily) revised my original question to include essentials. I hope grep will get me there!

Comment: [grep](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/grep/info) as tagged is a command line UNIX tool to do `g/re/p`. There's nothing about the code you posted or the text of your question that makes me think you're using the UNIX tool `grep` so you shouldn't be using the tag for that tool. You appear to be using some other tool that has a function named `grep()` - all I'm saying is that if that's the case then replace the tag on your question for the UNIX tool `grep` with the tag for whatever tool you ARE using instead so you can get help from people who know whatever tool that is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. This should include a sample dataset and your expected result. Ideally, the sample dataset can be used as a test case to demonstrate the suggested solutions work as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grepl()` instead of `grep()` to get a boolean vector which tells you which strings contain the pattern.  On these vectors, you can use logical conditions like `&`:

```
new.data <- old.data[grepl("text1", old.data$V5)&grepl("text2", old.data$V5), ]
```